Non-empty sequence of nested open intervals do not have a common point.
$\textbf{Problem}$: Show that the open intervals $J_n = (0,\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ do not have a common point in $\mathbb{R}$.
$\textbf{Proof}$: Suppose, by contradiction, that $x$ is a common point for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. First, observe that each $J_n$ is non-empty and they form a nested sequence in the sense that $$J_1 \supseteq J_2 \supseteq J_3 \dots $$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, $x$ belongs to each open interval $J_n = (0,\frac{1}{n})$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $x > 0$ then, by the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < x$. But this is not the case when the point $x$ is inside the interval $J_n = (0,\frac{1}{n})$, in other words, $0 < x < \frac{1}{n}$.  Hence, $x$ cannot be a common point.
$\textbf{Question}$: Is it necessary to say that the intersection is just the point ${0}$, or is it sufficient to conclude from the Archimedean property? Thank you
Edit: So, the proof just relies on the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is Archimedean, and it is a direct consequence of the Archimedean property.

It's false so probably not. The intersection is empty.

So, the argument looks fine except arguing for n tends to infinity?

Fineish, but you don't have to put your intervals in any particular or have n tending anywhere. The Archimedean principle as you've stated it immediately says no x>0 is in all the intervals and obviously neither is any x<=0 because no such x is in any interval. So Bob's your uncle.

I just updated the proof and thanks for the comment.
